# coding style: use parameter or instance variable?

Tags: coding-style

I often have functions which take a parameter, set an instance variable to that parameter, and then do other things, e.g.:

```
def updateFoo(self, foo):
    self.foo = foo
    fooProcessor1(foo)
    fooProcessor2(self.foo)
```

Do you prefer to pass the parameter itself, as in `fooProcessor1`, or the newly-set instance variable, as in `fooProcessor2`? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function named `setFoo()` really shouldn't do anything more than setting `foo` unless it is computing and caching a value derived from foo, in which case I would advise something along the lines of:

```
  def setFoo(self, foo):
      self.foo = foo
      self.__fooUpdated()

  def __fooUpdated(self):
      # Recompute values derived from foo, dispatch signal to listeners, etc.
```

Of the options you suggested, I prefer `fooProcessor1(foo)`. That said, it is mostly a matter of personal preference. As long as you are consistent, I don't think it matters all that much.

Comment: i didn't mean it to just be a setter functoin, these funcs do other things too. changed the func name

Comment: @Claudiu - as a matter of style, you are setting `self.foo` and then recomputing things based on the new value of `self.foo`. It may be splitting hairs, but that's not quite the same as recomputing values based on the *parameter* `foo`. Because of that I like Michael's solution here, which separates the concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Coders should be lazy. self. is way too much to type at 1 am.